# trying to initialize a list as a ADT

Tags: c, list, abstract-data-type

Hi i'm trying to initialize a list as an ADT but i'm having some difficulties. first of all, i have 3 files: main.c, pgList.h,pgList.c and everything is linked correctly.
so i call this function in main.c:

```
pgList_t pgList = pgList_init();
```

i have a pointer to a wrapper where i have the head of my list in pgList.h:

```
typedef struct pgList_s *pgList_t;
```

and of course i declare the function here like this:

```
pgList_t pgList_init();
```

in the pgList.c i declare my struct like this to make an ADT:

```
typedef struct node *link;
struct node{pg_t val; link next;};
struct pgList_s{link head;int N;};
```

so to initialize it, i want to return an empty wrapper (pgList_s):

```
pgList_t pgList_init(){
pgList_t x;
x->head=NULL;
x->N=0;
return x;
}
```

but the prorgam won't go past this function and i don't know what i'm doing wrong. thanks for the help and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: What do you mean by "ADT", exactly?

Comment: Abstract Data Types, maybe they have other names but in my university they are called like that

Comment: If you are having an error, you need to show the error, and also a [mcve], not just snippets.

Comment: Re "*but the prorgam won't go past this function*", What does it do instead?

Comment: it gives me a weird exit code: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: 0xC0000005 aka SIGSEGV is the result of a protection violation. Commonly the result of dereferencing a NULL pointer. `-fsanitize=address` is a great way of debugging memory problems with gcc and clang.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is universally reviled practice:

```c
typedef struct pgList_s *pgList_t;
```

Replace

```c
typedef struct pgList_s *pgList_t;

pgList_t x;
```

with

```c
typedef struct pgList_s pgList_t;

pgList_t *x;
```

The problem is that you use `x` without ever initializing it.

```c
// Returns NULL and sets errno on error.
pgList_t *pgList_init(void) {
   pgList_t *x = malloc(sizeof(pgList_t));
   if (!x)
      return NULL;

   x->head = NULL;
   x->N    = 0;
   return x;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much that risolved the issue, may i ask why is it a relived practice? my professor taught me that way weird.

Comment: If we don't see the `*`, we don't expect a pointer. At the very least, use something like "ptr" in the type name if it's a pointer type.

Comment: @ikegami I guess you're not a fan of Win32's headers too, eh?

Comment: @Dai, Windows pointer types do use `PTR` in their name. Or at least "LP" in some commonly-used types (e.g. `LPTCTR`)

Comment: Well it totally makes sense if you're doing a project with more people, but i'm actually doing these programs as homework for my uni so i'm the only one touching the code. will surely keep that in mind in the future, thanks!

Comment: @ikegami Often it's abbreviated to just `LP` though as in `LPCWSTR` - or just `P` as in `PLONG64` - there's [plenty of offenders in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types).

Comment: @Dai, The point is that it is communicated.